# How to transfer one label value to another label for displaying video Name using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

Below is my label code under a repeater with image:

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="innerRep" runat="server">
               <ItemTemplate>

                <li> 
                 <img src=' <%#Eval("ImageName") %>' alt='<%#Eval("ImgUrl") %>' width="100" height="60" onclick = "ChangeImage(this)" style="cursor:pointer;" />
               <br />   <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%#Bind("VideoName") %>' ></asp:Label>
                 </li>

                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:Repeater>
```

When I click the particular image using image onclick, then the video will start playing in I frame, as well as I need video name should come below I frame in a label.

For that I used one label2 for displaying the video name below the video player.

Comment: Did you try passing in the label value as a parameter to : ChangeImage(this, labelValue) and setting that to label2 using jquery/javascript?

Comment: No, actually I am new in j query and Java script. I do not know to pass values and my java script code is : My java script code:
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
    function ChangeImage(getID)
  {
    var targetID = document.getElementById("centralImage");
    targetID.src=getID.alt;
   
  }
 </script>

Comment: Please see my answer, I have provided some sample code.

Comment: Your code is working perfect but want to pass another parameter for like video name, like that video size to another label below of the video name label. How Siva.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter the img tag within repeater to:

```
<img src=' <%#Eval("ImageName") %>' alt='<%#Eval("ImgUrl") %>' width="100" height="60" onclick = "ChangeImage(this,'<%#Eval("VideoName")' )" style="cursor:pointer;" />
```

I assume that you keep a html span(id=spnPlayingVideoName) for brevity, below the iframe
then within javascript you can do something like:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function ChangeImage(getID, playingVideoName) 
{ 
    //Set label value in JavaScript
    //document.getElementById("spnPlayingVideoName").value=playingVideoName;

    //Set label value in jQuery
    $("#spnPlayingVideoName").text(playingVideoName);

    var targetID = document.getElementById("centralImage"); 
    targetID.src=getID.alt; 
} 
</script>
```

This code is not tested thoroughly, but provided for a quick idea.

**Note:** Make sure that adding extra parameter to "ChangeImage(...)" function does not break other code.
If it break some other code, you may write a separate function(Eg: UpdateVideoLabel(...)) and call that as well from "onclick" event of img tag.

Comment: Your code is working perfect but want to pass another parameter for like video name, like that video size to another label below of the video name label. How Siva.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
$('img').click(function(){
//make a variable with the value of a label1 based on the selected img - in your given code you can achieve this by the example bellow or using $(this).next().next().text() - > <br /> is element as well.
var videoname = $(this).parent().find("label1").text();
$('label2').text(videoname);
});
});
```

Comment: Finding by ID for ASP.NET server controls is a bit tricky, since they will be auto-generated by appending parent panel ids etc.,  especially in versions earlier to ASP.NET4.0.

Comment: Searching them by ID inside repeater is even trickier I believe, but this is just showing the concept based on the information we have :) Thanks for pointing that out tho.